# How to split result of MySql union Query from 2 columns to 4

Tags: mysql, sql, database, select, group-by

i'm executing this mysql query

```sql
select
    merchant_id, count(*)
from
    OrderDetails
where
    OrderDetails.delivery_date between '2019-07-24 00:00:00' and '2019-11-25 23:59:59' 
group by
    merchant_id

union all

select
    merchant_id, count(order_status_id)
from
    OrderDetails
where
    OrderDetails.delivery_date BETWEEN '2019-07-24 00:00:00' and '2019-11-25 23:59:59'
group by
    merchant_id, order_status_id
having
    order_status_id = 10

union

select
    merchant_id, count(order_status_id)
from
    OrderDetails
where
    OrderDetails.delivery_date between '2019-07-24 00:00:00' and '2019-11-25 23:59:59'
group by
    merchant_id, order_status_id
having
    order_status_id = 11;
```

but it return all results in two column, I want it to have in 4 , like **id** , **count**, **return**, **delivered** any suggestion please

Answer (score 1):

You need `sum()` and `count()`, you can ignore your `union`.

```
select merchant_id
    , count(1)
    , sum(case when order_status_id = 10 then 1 else 0 end) as returned
    , sum(case when order_status_id = 11 then 1 else 0 end) as delivered
from  OrderDetails 
where delivery_date between '2019-07-24 00:00:00' and '2019-11-25 23:59:59' 
group by merchant_id
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a slight tweak on Metal's solution.  In MySQL, I would use:

```
select merchant_id, count(*),
       sum( order_status_id = 10 ) as returned,
       sum( order_status_id = 11 ) as delivered
from OrderDetails 
where delivery_date >= '2019-07-24' and
      deliver_date < '2019-11-26' 
group by merchant_id ;
```

The bigger change is to the date logic.  It is just much simpler to use `>=` and `<`.  Further, it is more accurate -- unless you mean to exclude the last second on the last date.

The `sum()` are just a convenience in MySQL.  You can "sum" boolean expressions to count the number of true values.